# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; invalid property value

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why this isn't working. I put it in my html and body and it still says invalid property value and is crossed out. I was first trying to use it in my media queries but it didn't work there. Does anyone know a potential reason to why it doesn't work for me? Thank you!!

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#FCF5F4;
    font-family:webfont;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

[image: This is the error I get.]

Comment: Because it's not supported in Firefox/IE/Edge/whichever browser you use to look into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported by any browser. See at the bottom of this .[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling)

Comment: On the chrome browser

Comment: Maybe your browser got updated? Anyway you shouldn't use it.

Comment: What should i use instead?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You should just not use it, since it appears that is only for iOS and what it does is only: "touch
    Use momentum-based scrolling, where the content continues to scroll for a while after finishing the scroll gesture and removing your finger from the touchscreen. The speed and duration of the continued scrolling is proportional to how vigorous the scroll gesture was. Also creates a new stacking context."