# How can I apply “inertia” style horizontal scrolling to a div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I have successfully implemented horizontal scrolling on [wikiprop.org](https://wikiprop.org) but [the example I followed](https://benfrain.com/horizontal-scrolling-area-css-overflow-ios/) has this inertia/momentum effect, where you can swipe and it’ll continue scrolling and gradually slow down—as is common across the web.

Why doesn’t my horizontal scroll do the same? On my machine, at least, the scroll feels “sticky” meaning it doesn’t continue scrolling to a gradual stop when I do the “fast swipe” gesture.

Much appreciate any support, and please let me know if this is not clear enough.

Comment: Which browser is giving you problems? I'm testing on iOS12.1 and it's smooth.

Comment: Sorry, should have added that. It is perfect on iOS, but not smooth on Chrome desktop. That’s what I’m trying to troubleshoot—desktop performance.

Comment: I think things scroll smoothly in iOS because, despite the errors in the rendered `CSS`, smooth scroll is the default on iOS.

Comment: See this answer for a possible vanilla JavaScript solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69583941/2987930

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your site in Chrome with the developer tools opened. If you look at the following screenshot, you'll see that Chrome is only rendering some of the `CSS`. It appears you wrote your styles using `SCSS` and an error occurred in the pre-processing step. Since browsers can't read `SCSS`, you can imagine all the possible issues that might arise.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy; my immediate reaction to this would be to add !important lol.

I used a bootstrap theme, which does leverage SCSS, but both of these classes are just CSS in my style.css file. I’ll keep troubleshooting, but was mainly curious to know if desktop browsers had some kind of limitation on horizontal scrolling smoothness.

Comment: @JérémyChevallier :) Outputting valid `CSS` is probably the most `!important` thing you can do. Your code should work after that.

Comment: @JérémyChevallier Oh, and if my answer works for you, please select it.

Comment: further research shows that webkit-overflow-scrolling [isn’t even supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409991/webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-invalid-property-value).

Comment: Okay, once you get the `CSS` compiling correctly, check out [this link](https://codepen.io/colinlord/pen/oZNoOO). Adding `white-space: nowrap` to your container really messes things up, though. So you'll possibly have to make some other changes.