# Horizontal Scroll with Momentum in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a project where I want a horizontal slider. I made this slider draggable and found a bit of code that made it slide with momentum. I managed to make this horizontal scroll with mouse wheel, but I don't know how to make it work with this momentum effect. How can I do ?

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec dapibus leo. Nunc odio massa, tempor eu aliquam vel, viverra vitae est. Suspendisse dignissim nisi arcu. Vivamus non sem et mi auctor varius. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin blandit malesuada sem, vel gravida tortor volutpat nec. Ut eu vestibulum neque.

(Sorry but I don't think I can be more precise and I need to show you the code to make you understand)

```js
// Slider dragging

const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    isDown = true;
    slider.classList.add('active');
    startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
    cancelMomentumTracking();
});

slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    isDown = false;
    slider.classList.remove('active');
});

slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    isDown = false;
    slider.classList.remove('active');
    beginMomentumTracking();
});

slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    if(!isDown) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    const walk = (x - startX); //scroll-fast
    var prevScrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
    slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
    velX = slider.scrollLeft - prevScrollLeft;
});

// Momentum 

var velX = 0;
var momentumID;

slider.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    cancelMomentumTracking();
});  

function beginMomentumTracking(){
    cancelMomentumTracking();
    momentumID = requestAnimationFrame(momentumLoop);
}

function cancelMomentumTracking(){
    cancelAnimationFrame(momentumID);
}

function momentumLoop(){
    slider.scrollLeft += velX * 2;
    velX *= 0.95; 
    if (Math.abs(velX) > 0.5){
        momentumID = requestAnimationFrame(momentumLoop);
    }
}

//Scroll

const scrollContainer = document.querySelector(".slider");

scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY;
});
```

```css
.slider {
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 75vh;
    cursor: grab;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
}

.slider:active {
    cursor: grabbing;
}

.slider::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.slide {
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 70%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: crimson;
}

.slide:last-child {
    margin-right: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" data-scroll-container="">
            <div class="slide" id="slide-1"></div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide-2"></div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide-3"></div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide-4"></div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide-5"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your function. It's not as smooth as I'd like it to be, but it does the job:

```js
scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
    // scrollContainer.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY;

    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        scrollContainer.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: scrollContainer.scrollLeft + (evt.deltaY * 2), behavior: "smooth" });
    });
});
```

What I've done is I replaced the `scrollLeft` action with `scrollTo` which has a `smooth` behaviour parameter. I have also added `evt.deltaY * 2` as, in my case, it wasn't scrolling enough.

What I'd like to improve is scroll snapping when using the wheel and less "jankyness".

See a demo here (scroll to the blue/purple boxes) - [JavaScript Smooth Horizontal Scrolling](https://getbutterfly.com/)

[image: JavaScript Smooth Horizontal Scrolling]